# The name does not exist in the current context in invariant method

Tags: c#, code-contracts, invariants

I am trying to use invariants(code contracts library) in my program inside a carpark class where all my methods are implemented but "The name does not exist in the current context" appears.The highlighted words appeared to make the problem. The **conferenceID and parkingID** are coming from two different classes which are outside the CarPark Class. Here's what i tried until now.

```
 class Program
{


    public class Conferences
    {
        public int conferenceID { get; set; }
        public Parking[] parkingArray { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    }

    public class Parking
    {
        public int parkingID { get; set; }
        public bool parkingIsReserved { get; set; }
        public bool parkingIsPurchased { get; set; }
        public bool parkingisReservedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }

       [ContractInvariantMethod]
        void ObjectInvariant()
        {
            Contract.Invariant(**conferenceID** >= 0 && conferenceID <= totalConferences);
            Contract.Invariant(**parkingID** >= 0 && parking <= maxParkingSpaces);
            Contract.Invariant(parkingID <= availableParkings);
        }
```

Comment: Where are they declared?

Comment: @Haytam please see the edited code. The ObjectInvariat() method is implemented in the CarPark class

Answer (score 1):

Your Contract Invariants should be in the same class as the fields you want to test, a.k.a `Parking` in your example:

```
public class Parking
{
    public int parkingID { get; set; }
    public bool parkingIsReserved { get; set; }
    public bool parkingIsPurchased { get; set; }
    public bool parkingisReservedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

   [ContractInvariantMethod]
    void ObjectInvariant()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(**conferenceID** >= 0 && conferenceID <= totalConferences);
        Contract.Invariant(**parkingID** >= 0 && parking <= maxParkingSpaces);
        Contract.Invariant(parkingID <= availableParkings);
    }
}
```